# What will happen when we have a finally block as well as try with resource used together?

Tags: java

Please consider the below example, whether scanner will be closed still? how does it works whether it be called as first statement or last statement?

```
try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("test.txt"))) {
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
    } 
} catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
    fnfe.printStackTrace(); 
} 
finally {   
    System.out.println("finally"); 
}
```

Comment: Java Language Specification [14.20.3.2. Extended try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3.2) -- sure the scanner will be closed, but `finally` is, as usual, called last

Comment: You can easily verify this by creating your own class that implements `AutoCloseable`. Add a print statement in the `close` method and you'll see that it's being called when used as resource. As well as the print statement in the `finally` block

Answer (score -1):

A sample snippet helped to understand,

```
public class DummyClosable implements AutoCloseable {

    private final String message;

    public DummyClosable(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }


    @Override
    public void close() throws Exception {
        System.out.println(message);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try(DummyClosable dummyClosable1 = new DummyClosable("Auto Close First");
            DummyClosable dummyClosable2 = new DummyClosable("Auto Close Second");) {

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } finally {
            System.out.println("finally called");
        }
    }

}
```

Found that both autoclose close method and finally block statements are getting called.

Output:

- Auto Close Second
- Auto Close First
- finally called

Interesting thing is that resources are closed in reversed order.